# angular default drop down value 2 way bound

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a drop down in Angular that is a 2 way bound FORM control. When the form loads all I want to do is set a default value on the bound value so it displays that value in the drop down. When I change the value in the drop down and print to console I see the binding is correct. However the first time it loads the default value is not displayed in the drop down (not preselected) . In this sample when the form loads "cow" should be the default selected item but it is not working on page load.  Please advise what is wrong in the code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-initial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmattically assign the value to your `FormControl`...

```
   ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.animalControl.setValue(this.animals[2]);
    this.animalControl.markAsTouched();
    console.log('FormControl Value: '+JSON.stringify(this.animalControl.value))
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-initial-atr11t?embed=1&file=app/select-hint-error-example.ts

---

**Revision**

Use of `ngModel` with `FormControl` has been decprecated and is removed from Angular 7... you should start getting use to accessing values from the FormControl.

```
console.log('FormControl Value: '+JSON.stringify(this.animalControl.value))
```

https://next.angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

> This has been deprecated for a few reasons. First, developers have
>   found this pattern confusing. It seems like the actual ngModel
>   directive is being used, but in fact it's an input/output property
>   named ngModel on the reactive form directive that simply approximates
>   (some of) its behavior. Specifically, it allows getting/setting the
>   value and intercepting value events. However, some of ngModel's other
>   features - like delaying updates withngModelOptions or exporting the
>   directive - simply don't work, which has understandably caused some
>   confusion.
>
> In addition, this pattern mixes template-driven and reactive forms
>   strategies, which we generally don't recommend because it doesn't take
>   advantage of the full benefits of either strategy. Setting the value
>   in the template violates the template-agnostic principles behind
>   reactive forms, whereas adding a FormControl/FormGroup layer in the
>   class removes the convenience of defining forms in the template.
>
> To update your code before v7, you'll want to decide whether to stick
>   with reactive form directives (and get/set values using reactive forms
>   patterns) or switch over to template-driven directives.

Comment: it also worked when i changed [(value)] to [(ngModel)] and now iam scratching my head as to what the difference is. Will google to see if I find info. Thanks

Comment: the [(ngModel)] change i did was in my real code not sample used here. That bound variable was something like Customer.ZipCode..

Comment: Please see revision to answer with further detail.